# blackberry - Connecting to MySQL using JDBC and eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, blackberry, jdbc

I have made a login screen in eclipse for a blackberry device and would like to verify if these details are correct so that the user can log in by connecting to MySql - with the login details table in it.

I have added the connector/j to my project and have the apache and MySQL setup. 
I need to know how to write the code to connect and verify the login details

Thanks

Comment: This question is too broad. Work in steps. Your first step is probably just learning JDBC. Vendor's own JDBC tutorial would be the best starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html

Comment: I don't know any JDBC for BlackBerry

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using a connection to a server-side script to do the connecting and login checks. A simple CGI script over HTTPS should do fine.

Comment: Thanks but i dont know where to even begin with this method?

Comment: @user1075785 - Write a CGI script on the server that accepts login credentials, connects to the data base and does the check, and responds with an indication of success or failure. (A 1-character text/plain document containing 0 or 1 would be fine in the simplest sense.) On the device side, write code to POST to your script and read the response, just like you would do with any other web site. (There's lots of sample code for how to do this.)